# Unable to submit form in jQuery mobile

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

Below is a form that I am trying to submit in jQuery mobile(1.4). But unable to submit. Can someone please suggest where I am going wrong ?

```
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="set_location_page" data-url="map-page">
    <div data-role="content">
        <form id='g_address_form' action="/confirm_address/" method="POST" >{% csrf_token %}
            <input id='g_door_no' type="text" name="g_door_no">
            <input id='g_street' type="text" name="g_street">
                <input id='submit_g_address' type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>    
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found out that jQuery [uses ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16782665/2534233)   in passing forms. Therefore by setting `data-ajax="false"` solved the issue

```
<div data-role="page" id="set_location_page" data-url="map-page" data-ajax="false">
```