# jquery mobile form post value not working

Tags: php, jquery-mobile

form.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/jmobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
    <script src="lib/jmobile/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/jmobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<head>
<body class="ui-page-theme-a">
  <div data-role="page">
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">

<form action = "aksi.php" method = "post">
    <input type="text" name="cari" placeholder="cari informasi...">
    <input type="submit" value="PROSES">
</form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

aksi.php

```
<?php
  $lihat = $_POST['cari'];
  echo $lihat;
?>
```

Why aksi.php cannot get value from form.php ?

if i cannot include jquery mobile that script it's working well.

Comment: Please include relevant information in the question.  Stack Overflow is not a scavenger hunt.

Comment: What is echo'd? Have you tried `isset($_POST['cari'])` to confirm? Any errors?

Comment: How are you validating this behavior?  The code shown should produce the expected behavior, though there could be more to this process which you haven't told us.  (Also note that this has *nothing* to do with jQuery, mobile or otherwise...)

Comment: isset just checking if value is empty or not.

Comment: Right. How about adding `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to gather errors.

Comment: try running a var_dump($_POST)

to see whats being sent

Comment: i'm sorry if my speak cannot very well

Comment: jQuery mobile is a different animal than other JS frameworks and utilizes `rel="external"` when referencing (I have worked with this in the past). You left out what could be relevant code. As posted, this question will remain unsolved until we know exactly what we're dealing with, if ran from a hosted server, or from your own PC and "how".

Comment: please don't dump code in comments, it belongs in your question. Plus that may not be full code.

Comment: Consult http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770276/jquery-mobile-form-submit-not-working and add `rel="external"` inside your form tags. There could be an issue with `<div data-role="page">`. See also https://forum.jquery.com/topic/rel-external-for-forms

Comment: anyone can help me please ?

Comment: still not working.

i following this tutorial from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/tryit.asp?filename=tryjqmob_forms_buttons)

tutorial in w3schools is working well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JQuery Mobile will post the form via AJAX unless you add the `data-ajax="false"` to your `form`. So your PHP should be getting the Posted data under `$_POST['cari']`.

Tested in JSFiddle with both.

`data-ajax="true"` - http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/mco3uben/

`data-ajax="false"` - http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/mco3uben/1/

If you review your Console for the first, you will see a new HTTP request is posted to the `action` and the response echo'd back by jsfiddle. The second brings you to a new page and echos the entry.

Both should work as you have it configured. You may want to add some HTML to your PHP to allow JQM to hook into it:

```
<?php
  $lihat = $_POST['cari'];
  echo "<html><body><div data-role='page'><div role='main' class='ui-content'>\r\n";
  echo $lihat;
  echo "</div></div></body></html>";
?>
```